# change color of Twitter bootstrap progress bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking at Twitter bootstrap. I am trying to change the color of the progress bar, but cannot actually even show the bar.

My code looks like this. I have no idea what is wrong and have tried everything. Perhaps it is the version of bootstrap that I am using

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="bar" style="width: 60%;"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.bar {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set the `height` of the `.bar` element to `100%`, otherwise it's height will be 0 (because it doesn't have any content).

```css
.bar {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="progress">
  <div class="bar" style="width: 60%;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears you're not using the right CSS class for the bar itself. Please try using the class "progress-bar" instead of "bar". For example:

**HTML**

```html
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 60%;"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.progress-bar {
  background-color: green;
}
```

Please refer to this reference:
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress

Comment: hey man, i was looking to change this one - what if you change `progress-bar` to `pink` - does it work then? http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#progress. Thanks for your help though

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply man. Are you asking if you could use pink instead of green for the background color? If so, then yes, there's a CSS color code for pink.

Comment: By the way, @phantom

Comment: By the way, @phantom, from your code at the top, you're referencing Bootstrap version 3.3.7. That version uses the "progress-bar" class for the inside track of the progress bar component. The old "bar" class was for older version like the one in your link version 2.3.2.